# How to set a rule for buying two products together to reduce the total price?

Tags: magento

I am trying to make a block which shows two products in it with a rule that if a customer bought these two products together the total amount will be reduce by some extent.

e.g. if product A is of $100 and B is of $75, then both will be buy together for $150.

Can anyone has an idea how to apply these kind of promotion rules in magento. I really need to do this as the client need this kind of functionality on its product view page.

Comment: Can it be product C which is A+B at the price of 150?

Comment: No i want to add both the product simultaneously.
i.e. I am creating a new block which shows this promotion and below this an add to cart button, so that when I click on add to cart both products should be added in the cart with the price of 150.

Comment: So if the customer remove product B from his shopping cart Product A must become $100 again and vice versa?

Comment: yes thats right. I want exactly like this. Do you know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a default functionality to create bundle products.

Use following url for reference:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that you could use:

1) Setting up a bundled product (with a Price Type = Fixed Price), setting product A and product B to be its children and setting $150 as its price.

However, there are few limitations to this solution:

The customer can't just add product A or product B to cart separately from the bundled product page, he can only add them together. That is the customer will need to go to a separate page to purchase product A (or product B) standalone.

Once the user added the bundled product to his cart, he can't just remove one child product from the cart (e.g product A) - he has to remove both.

2) You can use an extension for it. One of the extensions that implement this functionality is [Bundled Discount](https://www.mexbs.com/bundled-discount-magento2-extension). It allows you to set the product A and the product B and set the special price whenever they are purchased together (eg: $150).

It also allows you to create a separate page for the bundled promotion. This way, the user can select whether he wants to add only the product A for $100, the product B for $75, all both for $150.

The user can also remove one of the products from his cart and only pay for another product (eg: the user removes the product A from his cart and only pays $75 for the product B).

**Disclaimer: I am the CEO of the company that developed the Bundled Discount extension.**